# Change Dash to Dock setting on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock, gnome-dash

I prefer to have Dash to Dock minimized, so I use a command

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/extend-height false.
```

The problem is, when I tried this command in the new Ubuntu 18.10 installation, it didn't work as expected and there is extra vertical line visible. Is there a way to get rid of it?